# How to change behaviour of Rails belongs_to

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, belongs-to

I have two models:

```
class Sentence < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sentence_id, :authority_name #...
end

class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :headline, :note, :sentence_id
end
```

I would like to know how to create `belongs_to :sentence` association on `Rule` which will behave like this pseudo-SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM rules 
INNER JOIN sentences ON rules.sentence_id = sentences.sentence_id;
```

**Edit:**

I would like get something like that

```
rule = Rule.find 797 
# we all know how SQL query will look like...
rule.sentence  
# => SELECT * FROM sentences 
     INNER JOIN rules ON rules.sentence_id = sentences.sentence_id 
     WHERE rules.id = 797
```

Comment: Is the catch here that you want to get all the rules that belong to any sentence (i.e., there are some rules where sentence_id is null)? If every rule belongs to a sentence, why doesn't the basic `has_many :rules` for the Sentence model and `belongs_to :sentence` for the Rule model accomplish what you want?

Comment: Added more info to question. :)

Comment: Seems to me like that basic association setup would accomplish what you are looking for. What is it about that approach that's lacking?

Comment: That approach is lacking settings for foreign_key. When you do basic associations like that `belongs_to :sentence` you still get JOIN by `INNER JOIN sentences ON sentences.id = rules.sentence_id` INSTEAD OF `INNER JOIN sentences ON sentences.sentence_id = rules.sentence_id`. I want last join. Read carefully. :P :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, is `sentence_id` the primary key of the `sentences` table?

If so then you just need to explicitly set that column as the primary key.

```
class Sentence < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :sentence_id
end

class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sentence
end
```

If `sentence_id` is not the primary key, then you need to specify it as the "primary key" of the association.  I didn't get a chance to test the code, but it should be like this:

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sentence, :primary_key => :sentence_id
end
```

Comment: Also, `set_primary_key` is being deprecated. Use `self.primary_key= 'sentence_id'`

Answer (score 0):

In relational database theory, foreign keys ***ALWAYS*** go to *primary* keys.  To get active record to generate the SQL you want, set the primary key.

```
class Sentence < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :sentence_id
```

I think that's what you want, but here's an alternative.  To do a custom join, use the joins() method and supply the string that you want in your SQL.